# Efficient counter for counting ties in survival times (R)

Tags: r, performance, counter

Survival times are numeric time measurments given in an ordered vector of size `1 x n` in `x`. For two time points in `x` a tie is defined as `x[i] == x[j]` where ordering coerces `i` and `j` to be adjacent, `i+1 == j`, or `k` indices apart if all intermediate times are ties.

Given `x` I need an efficient counter that returns (1) the vector of unique times (no doubles), (2) for each time a count of ties.

Below is my rudmentary code. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

We have some times with ties on indices 5 and 6 and 9 and 10.

```
x = 1:10
x[5] = 6
x[10] = 9
```

Tie indentifier:

```
x_new <- ties <- numeric()
n <- length(x)
i = 1; k=1

while( i <= n ){
  d = NA
  if(i+1<=n) {d = x[i] - x[i+1]}
  j = 0

  while(d==0 & (i+j+1)<=n){
    j = j + 1
    d = x[i] - x[i+j+1]
  }

  x_new[k] = x[i]
  ties[k]  = j + 1
  i = i + j + 1
  k = k + 1
}
```

Giving desired result:

```
cbind(x_new,ties)
     x_new ties
[1,]     1    1
[2,]     2    1
[3,]     3    1
[4,]     4    1
[5,]     6    2
[6,]     7    1
[7,]     8    1
[8,]     9    2
```

Comment: Do you want `rle(x)`?

Comment: Based on the definition of your vector ties can be only in a row. So, I think `table(x)` or `data.frame(table(x))` will work as well.

Comment: @AntoniosK true I realize now I needed explicit code because another action needs to be perfomed in the first `while` loop. see comment below. perhaps I will ammend the question

Answer (score 1):

Just use `rle`

```
sapply(rle(sort(x)), cbind)
#     lengths values
#[1,]       1      1
#[2,]       1      2
#[3,]       1      3
#[4,]       1      4
#[5,]       2      6
#[6,]       1      7
#[7,]       1      8
#[8,]       2      9
```

Comment: Thanks. I needed explicit code because for each `i` an additional action needs to be performed on another variable of the same length of `x` which I omitted in the code. But your answer is exhaustive for the problem I posed. Maybe I will ammend my question.